# jQuery - Adding a link to html()

Tags: jquery

I have a link inside of a div element. The link has a click listener.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#theLink').click(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
})

<div id="myElement"><a class="myLink" id="theLink">Click here</a></div>
```

At some point in my application, I have to clear the div elements contents, and then have to re-write them again later. When I rewrite the link using .html(''), I lose the click listener and the link doesn't work.

```
$('#myElement').html(''); // clear element

$('#myElement').html('<a class="myLink" id="theLink">Click here</a>');
```

Do I need to add a new listener to get this link working again?

Comment: Use `.live()` or `.on()` instead of `.click()`

Comment: @ShadowWizard this isn't a comment, because it's the answer :)

Comment: Why must you destroy the element? Why not just `hide/show` it? It doesn't make sense to continuously destroy and recreate the same element, even if methods like `on()` or `live()` let you.

Comment: +1 @ShadowWizard. I tried using .on() without any success but .live() worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @MartinG Try my demo.. which shows you how to use .on and not use .live for such scenarios... .live parses your whole dom on every changes to bind the listener.. which is an expensive task.

Comment: @SKS I will try your demo shortly, I'll be back. Don't like the sound of expensive task :)

Comment: Cheers @Ahmet and Martin.. feel free to accept SKS answer it's exactly my intention plus great demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and specify the container of the link to have it listen after being removed and added again.

**Edit:** You can read about below approach in their [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). See under section Direct and delegated events.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/BsCxg/) here

Something like below should work,

```
$('#myElement').on('click', '#theLink', function() {
  alert('HI!');
});
```

I think internally jQuery does something like below,

```
$('#myElement').click (function (e) {
    if (this.id == 'theLink') {
       alert('Hi!');
       e.stopPropogation();           
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use **[jQuery's on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** function (jQuery 1.7+). This will allow you to bind the click event to your element regardless of how many times you add and remove it.

For example:

```
$("#theLink").on("click", function(event){
    //do stuff;
});
```

**Update**: For jQuery versions earlier than 1.7 use either [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) or [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (depending on the exact jQuery version). The same syntax applies.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
$('#myElement').children('id!="myLink"').remove()
```

Should remove all children of the container div other than the link. However, I'm not sure if the selector expression inside children() is correctly formatted, so it might cause a syntax error. If so, please comment and I'll edit the answer.